Feedparser errors during SSl read operation when accessing NASDAQ RSS Feeds
By utliizing Python 3.12, Feedparser 6.0.11, ca-certificates installed
When attempting to read this RSS feed: https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=Financial+Advisors. Feedparser library returns this error.
https://www.nasdaq.com/feed/rssoutbound?category=Innovation
^CTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nckr/kiwichi/read.py", line 78, in <module>
    NewsFeed = feedparser.parse(url)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nckr/kiwichi/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/feedparser/api.py", line 216, in parse
    data = _open_resource(url_file_stream_or_string, etag, modified, agent, referrer, handlers, request_headers, result)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nckr/kiwichi/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/feedparser/api.py", line 115, in _open_resource
    return http.get(url_file_stream_or_string, etag, modified, agent, referrer, handlers, request_headers, result)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/nckr/kiwichi/venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages/feedparser/http.py", line 171, in get
    f = opener.open(request)
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 515, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 532, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 1348, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 1428, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 331, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/http/client.py", line 292, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/socket.py", line 707, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1252, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/ssl.py", line 1104, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyboardInterrupt

I tried setting the unverified SSL: context(Feedparser.parse() 'SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED') at the beginning of the script but still get this error.
if hasattr(ssl, '_create_unverified_context'):
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context

I'm assuming the global SSL setting will be magically used by the feedparsers lib and I don't need to pass it to it explicitly.
Is there another workaround or anyway to get more info regarding the actual error other than an SSL read error. Could also be a timeout error as well. However I can access the URL successful using curl on the command line.

It looks like you've cut off the actual exception that was raised from the end of your exception stacktrace. If possible, please provide a [mre].

@PresidentJamesK.Polk just added the complete error, it just makes a call to the feed url and then it just hangs waiting forever...

Thanks for the complete error. So you don't have any specific indication of a certificate problem, you were just guessing that might be the problem?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk yeah I am guessing because of the searching I have done so far. It could be something else.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I think I made some progress. I forced Curl to make the request using HTTP 1.1. Voila, it hangs. So it could be that the urllib does not support http2 or the server at the nasdaq url either is not configured properly for http 1.1 or only supports http2 even though it says it accepts http 1.1.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Then I made the request purely using pycurl in python since it supports http2 so that will fix my issue. I just have to use pycurl when feedparser doesn't work. Thanks.

Make it an answer!

Based on my repro steps. I was able to find out that the urllib does not work with http2 for the feeds that require http2 or where http1.1 does not work.
So I switched to using pycurl and then passing the response to feedparser and everything works. Hope it helps someone.
